# Steam hash sum mismatch and invalid file format errors

Tags: apt, steam, hash

I have Steam Beta installed, and when I just ran:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I got the following output:

```
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security InRelease
Ign http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid InRelease                                                                                                     
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net vivid InRelease                                                                                                         
Ign http://archive.canonical.com vivid InRelease                                                                                                     
Ign http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates InRelease                                   
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security Release.gpg [933 B]                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net vivid Release.gpg                                                                              
Hit http://archive.canonical.com vivid Release.gpg                                         
Ign http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports InRelease                                 
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security Release [63.5 kB]                          
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net vivid Release                                                                               
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid Release.gpg                                                                       
Hit http://archive.canonical.com vivid Release                                                       
Get:3 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates Release.gpg [933 B]                                  
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports Release.gpg                                          
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid Release                                  
Get:4 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates Release [63.5 kB]     
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net vivid/main amd64 Packages                                                
Hit http://archive.canonical.com vivid/partner Sources                                                                                       
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net vivid/main i386 Packages                                       
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports Release                                    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net vivid/main Translation-en                                                                          
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security/main Sources [29.9 kB]                                                          
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/main Sources                                                                          
Hit http://archive.canonical.com vivid/partner amd64 Packages         
Hit http://repo.steampowered.com precise InRelease                    
Hit http://archive.canonical.com vivid/partner i386 Packages                                                 
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security/restricted Sources [28 B]                                    
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/restricted Sources                                                                          
Hit http://archive.canonical.com vivid/partner Translation-en                                                
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security/universe Sources [13.2 kB]             
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/universe Sources                                        
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security/multiverse Sources [1,957 B]                                 
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/multiverse Sources                                                 
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security/main amd64 Packages [87.5 kB]       
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/main amd64 Packages                                   
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/restricted amd64 Packages                             
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/universe amd64 Packages                                                  
Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security/restricted amd64 Packages [28 B]                               
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/multiverse amd64 Packages                                                
Get:11 http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security/universe amd64 Packages [43.0 kB]                              
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/main i386 Packages                                                                  
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/restricted i386 Packages                                             
Get:12 http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [3,494 B]
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/universe i386 Packages                                               
Get:13 http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security/main i386 Packages [86.8 kB]       
Hit http://repo.steampowered.com precise/steam Sources                              
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/multiverse i386 Packages                                                 
Get:14 http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security/restricted i386 Packages [28 B]                                
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/main Translation-en_GB                                                          
Get:15 http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security/universe i386 Packages [43.0 kB]         
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/main Translation-en                                                                
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/multiverse Translation-en_GB                                             
Get:16 http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security/multiverse i386 Packages [3,675 B]                             
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/multiverse Translation-en                                                
Get:17 http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security/main Translation-en [44.9 kB]                                  
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/restricted Translation-en_GB                                     
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/restricted Translation-en                                                      
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security/multiverse Translation-en                                               
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/universe Translation-en_GB                                                     
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security/restricted Translation-en                 
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/universe Translation-en    
Get:18 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/main Sources [64.6 kB]
Get:19 http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security/universe Translation-en [27.1 kB]               
Hit http://repo.steampowered.com precise/steam amd64 Packages                                                      
Get:20 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/restricted Sources [28 B]              
Get:21 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/universe Sources [27.6 kB]             
Get:22 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/multiverse Sources [1,957 B]           
Get:23 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/main amd64 Packages [153 kB]           
Get:24 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [28 B]        
Get:25 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/universe amd64 Packages [84.0 kB]       
Hit http://repo.steampowered.com precise/steam i386 Packages                                        
Get:26 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [3,494 B]  
Get:27 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/main i386 Packages [151 kB]                      
Get:28 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/restricted i386 Packages [28 B]      
Get:29 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/universe i386 Packages [84.0 kB]              
Get:30 http://repo.steampowered.com precise/steam Translation-en_GB [151 B]                             
Get:31 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [3,675 B]                             
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/main Translation-en                                 
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/universe Translation-en
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/main Sources  
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/restricted Sources
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/universe Sources
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/multiverse Sources
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/main i386 Packages
Get:32 http://repo.steampowered.com precise/steam Translation-en [151 B]
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/restricted i386 Packages     
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/main Translation-en
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/multiverse Translation-en                       
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/restricted Translation-en                       
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/universe Translation-en
Fetched 1,087 kB in 12s (83.9 kB/s)                                                                                                                  
W: Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/repo.steampowered.com_steam_dists_precise_steam_i18n_Translation-en%5fGB.gz  Invalid file format

W: Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/repo.steampowered.com_steam_dists_precise_steam_i18n_Translation-en.gz  Invalid file format

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

So I decided to run it again, this time I got more errors in the output:

```
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net vivid InRelease
Ign http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid InRelease                                                                        
Ign http://archive.canonical.com vivid InRelease                                                                         
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security InRelease                                                                  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net vivid Release.gpg                                             
Ign http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates InRelease                                   
Hit http://archive.canonical.com vivid Release.gpg                                         
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security Release.gpg                                  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net vivid Release                                                 
Ign http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports InRelease                                 
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid Release.gpg                                         
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security Release                                      
Hit http://archive.canonical.com vivid Release                                             
Hit http://repo.steampowered.com precise InRelease                                         
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates Release.gpg                                 
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports Release.gpg          
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid Release                                                                           
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates Release                                                                                               
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports Release                                                                                             
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net vivid/main amd64 Packages                                                                                  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net vivid/main i386 Packages                                                                           
Get:1 http://repo.steampowered.com precise/steam Sources [151 B]                                                 
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net vivid/main Translation-en                                                                                 
Hit http://archive.canonical.com vivid/partner Sources                                                           
Hit http://archive.canonical.com vivid/partner amd64 Packages                                             
Get:2 http://repo.steampowered.com precise/steam amd64 Packages [151 B]                                    
Hit http://archive.canonical.com vivid/partner i386 Packages                                                      
Get:3 http://repo.steampowered.com precise/steam i386 Packages [151 B]                                     
Ign http://archive.canonical.com vivid/partner Translation-en                                                     
Get:4 http://repo.steampowered.com precise/steam Translation-en_GB [151 B]
Get:5 http://repo.steampowered.com precise/steam Translation-en [151 B]                               
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security/restricted Translation-en                            
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security/main Sources                                 
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security/restricted Sources                    
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security/universe Sources                                       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security/multiverse Sources                    
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security/main amd64 Packages                   
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security/restricted amd64 Packages              
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security/universe amd64 Packages                
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security/multiverse amd64 Packages              
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security/main i386 Packages                     
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security/restricted i386 Packages               
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security/universe i386 Packages                 
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security/multiverse i386 Packages               
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security/main Translation-en                    
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security/multiverse Translation-en                    
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security/universe Translation-en                      
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/main Sources        
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/restricted Sources
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/multiverse Sources
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/main i386 Packages
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/main Translation-en
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/main Sources
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/restricted Sources
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/universe Sources
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/multiverse Sources
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/main i386 Packages
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/main Translation-en_GB
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/main Translation-en
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/multiverse Translation-en_GB
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/restricted Translation-en_GB
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/universe Translation-en_GB
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid/universe Translation-en
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/main Sources
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/restricted Sources
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/universe Sources
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/multiverse Sources
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/main i386 Packages
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/main Translation-en
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/universe Translation-en
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/universe Sources
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-backports/universe Translation-en
Fetched 755 B in 7s (97 B/s)                                                                                                                         
W: Failed to fetch http://repo.steampowered.com/steam/dists/precise/steam/source/Sources  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch http://repo.steampowered.com/steam/dists/precise/steam/binary-amd64/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch http://repo.steampowered.com/steam/dists/precise/steam/binary-i386/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/repo.steampowered.com_steam_dists_precise_steam_i18n_Translation-en%5fGB.gz  Invalid file format

W: Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/repo.steampowered.com_steam_dists_precise_steam_i18n_Translation-en.gz  Invalid file format

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

And I dread to think what the output will be if I run the command again... So basically, here is my question, what do these errors mean? And what should I do about them?

And just as an additional note, Steam was running (and I was logged in) during the time that I got these errors. Logging out and fully exiting Steam didn't seam to help though.

---

**OS Information:**

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
Codename:   vivid
```

**Package Information:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From time to time I can watch that too, but for other repositories. The problem usually resolves itself.

The files are easily broken. Maybe they are just re-created on the server and you got an unfavorable situation or any programmer or administrator made a mistake. All people make mistakes.

In this case, no reason to be paranoid panda … **;)**

Comment: You were right, the errors have gone away by themselves now. :)